# JQuery getting the tr after clicking its content <a>

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class='ilink'> link text </a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class='ilink'> link text </a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in the jquery code, after clicking the link, I want to highlight the entire table row that the link is in. But how can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$("a.ilink").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
});
```

If you have a lot of rows, this would be more efficient (one copy of this vs. one for every `<a>`):

```
$("table").delegate("a.ilink", "click", function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: Good answer. I was going to recommend `parentsUntil()` but was unaware its collection contains all parent items as it walks up the DOM tree. closest makes perfect sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
#EDIT remove...  better options listed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.ilink').click(function() {
        $('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
    });
 });
```

Then you will need the highlight css class defined:

```
.hightlight { background-color:red; }
```